# jsplumb.connect is not working for second time after adding new source element in angular 4

Tags: jsplumb

I am using Angular 4, and I am trying to connect two elements using jsplumb connect plugin.

But it is working fine only for first time,
means if I am having 3 source elements and want to connect to a single target, then it will work fine, it will get connected.

But now if I add the 4th source element in that sources list programmatically, using the child component and then calling connect method, it's not working.

**Means once I used that jsplumb.connect function, and then added new source element to list and again calling to connect, it is not working.**

### parentCreateLine.component.ts

```
sourceIds = ['s1', 's2', 's3'];

/* this is step 1 intial call from ui */
showIntialConnection() {
   this.connectSourceToTargetUsingJSPlumb(this.sourceIds);
}

/* this function will be called from UI to add new source and then show connection */
addNewSourceToListAndConnect(){
   this.sourceIds.push('s4');
   this.connectSourceToTargetUsingJSPlumb(this.sourceIds);
}
connectSourceToTargetUsingJSPlumb(sourceIds) {
        console.log('create connection');
        jsPlumb.reset();
        let labelName;
            for (let i = 0; i < sourceIds.length; i++) {
                labelName = 'connection' + (i + 1);
                jsPlumb.connect({
                    connector: ['Flowchart', {stub: [212, 67], cornerRadius: 1, alwaysRespectStubs: true}],
                    source: sourceIds[i],
                    target: 'target0',
                    anchor: ['Right', 'Left'],
                    endpoint: 'Blank',
                    paintStyle: {stroke: '#B8C5D6', strokeWidth: 4},
                    overlays: [
                        ['Label', {label: labelName, location: 0, cssClass: 'connectingConnectorLabel'}]
                    ],
                });
            }
    }
```

Please help me.
I have tried with uuid also, but got the same output.
Please suggest me the correct way of doing it in Angular 4.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution,
I have created the instance of jsplumb in ngAfterViewInit, and then using it and
resetting in the proper order,

```
this.jsPlumbInstance.reset();
jsPlumb.reset();
this.jsPlumbInstance = jsPlumb.getInstance();
```

so that everytime will get the new instance.

### parentCreateLine.component.ts

```
jsPlumbInstance;
ngAfterViewInit() {
        jsPlumb.reset();
        this.jsPlumbInstance = jsPlumb.getInstance();
    }

connectSourceToTargetUsingJSPlumb(sourceIds) {
        this.jsPlumbInstance.reset();
        jsPlumb.reset();
        this.jsPlumbInstance = jsPlumb.getInstance();
        let labelName;
        for (let i = 0; i < sourceIds.length; i++) {
            labelName = 'connection' + (i + 1);
            this.jsPlumbInstance.connect({
               ... above code ...
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can share the common jsPlumb instance, Find code below
>   these works for me

**app.component.ts**

```
import { jsPlumb } from 'jsplumb';
constructor(private customService: CustomService) {
  customService.jsPlumbInstance = jsPlumb.getInstance();
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import {CustomService} from '...path to the service';

constructor(private customService: CustomService) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.jsPlumbInstance = this.customService.jsPlumbInstance;
   this.jsPlumbInstance.deleteEveryConnection();
   this.jsPlumbInstance.deleteEveryEndpoint();
   this.jsPlumbInstance.importDefaults({...}) 
}
```